# PHP - select and import text file data into textarea

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, textarea

I did search but i could not find the answer.

I want to have import button, from where the user will import text file from user computer and the data of text file should be visible in textarea.

I have this code to show in textarea but don't know how to select and get data from user computer.

```
$data = file_get_contents('userfile.txt');
echo '<textarea>', htmlspecialchars($data), '</textarea>';
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. The file should not save on server rather it just get the data and show in textarea.

Comment: Put '.' (dot) instead of ','(comma) around `htmlspecialchars($data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the

```
<input type="file" name="userfile">
```

Then send it to the server. You'll be able to get the file path via the global variable $_FILES:

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
echo '<textarea>' . htmlspecialchars($data). '</textarea>';
```

Then just paste it into your textarea. But don't forget to validate the user files (size, extention etc)

Comment: Please explain it more... Did not understand what you mean.